# How Can I load multiple Page (like browser tab) in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: .net, asp.net, client-side

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET3.5 with C#. I also using Telerik RadAjax Control. When user click the menu then open the page with a new tab(Like web Browser).I want to create, when user back any previous tab(page) the will be show the previous data without loading 2nd time( like browser tab). Is it Possible ? plz help me!

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may be best answered on the [Telerik Forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums) in the future. It's easier to share complete demos for Telerik-specific solutions there.

In this specific case, the RadTabStrip with the RadMultiPage are the tools you are probably using. With these tools, you do not need to fire an additional PostBack when changing between tabs. Once the data has been loaded (it sounds like that's being done via AJAX UpdatePanels), you should be able to click between all loaded tabs.

You can even see a similar example live in the online demos:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/applicationscenarios/loadondemand/defaultcs.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Rad TabStrip for ASP.NET AJAX ought to do what you need.  (I'm sticking with a Telerik answer since you're already using their controls).

Comment: I just need client side store page after loading page(with new tab). when user back to any previous tab then show page without loading.(like browser tab)

Comment: Use the tab strip control... you won't have any postbacks/page reloads, so your data will always be there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when it will be multiple page(tab) is open then what can i do?

Comment: I dont understand your question?

Add tabs, add content to your tabs.  That should be all you need to do.

Comment: I need a tab for as a Individual page.